# Xamarin Forms NoSuchMethodError: no static method FormsViewGroup.sendViewBatchUpdate

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Updated Visual Studio Community and several NuGet packages in a working solution. Now when trying to run on an Android device or simulator getting the following error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lcom/xamarin/forms/platform/android/FormsViewGroup;.sendViewBatchUpdate(Landroid/view/View;FFIZFFFFFFFF)V"

Downgrading is not an option.

Tried `Clean All` and delete `bin` and `obj` as suggested [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3981) but it didn't help.
Tried different versions of `Xamarin.Forms`, also didn't help.

System:

> macOS 10.15.3
>
> Visual Studio Community 8.5
>
> Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.396
>
> Min API 21
>
> Target API 29

Comment: Have you upgraded the nugets in all 3 projects? Confirm you have updated Android SDKs in SDK manager as well.

Comment: All the NuGet packages are at their latest version. Have SDK versions 28.0.3 and all from 29.0.0 to 29.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `R8` is removing this method for some reason.
Adding the following `Proguard` rule fixed the issue:

```
-keep class com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.** {*;}
```

Comment: It seems that you solved your issue no, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members, thanks.

Comment: Sure. I can only do that 24h after asking. It didn't pass yet.